# Portaudio example "record_file.c" does not find "min"

Tags: c++, c, portaudio

First off, I alread got the smaller example `paex_record.c` to work.

I use MinGW on Windows8 and did compile portaudio from source, that's were I got the used `libportaudio-2.dll` from.

I set up a project in QtCreator (without gui) with following .pro-file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -LC:/Audio/patest/paex_record_file -llibportaudio-2
```

My folder `C:/Audio/patest/paex_record_file` looks like:

```
libportaudio-2.dll
main.cpp
pa_ringbuffer.c
pa_ringbuffer.h
pa_util.h
paex_record_file.pro
paex_record_file.pro.user
portaudio.h
```

I copied both `pa_ringbuffer` and `pa_util` to this folder after they were not found.
`Main.cpp`contains the whole example file `paex_record_file.c` from the portaudio source.

There is an error when calling the ringbuffer (line 246 and 271: [source](http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/paex__record__file_8c_source.html)):
`"min" was not declared in this scope`

I thought this example would directly run just like the `record.c` example.

Do I need to include further packages? I've tried `algorithm`, `math`, `std` and `using namespace std`, but still the error occurs. But I get the feeling it should work out off box, perhaps my include files or folder setup / linkage is not ok?

EDIT: Ok so I just defined a min-function on my own. Now it throws different error: 
`undefined reference to "PaUtil_GetRingBufferReadAvailable"`
and a couple more of this kind. There is probably a lib missing to be linked, having a look...

Comment: windows.h has macros for min and max which are probably interfering, try #define NOMINMAX before including it

Comment: This did not work. `define NOMINMAX` is also defined in `windows.h` if `RC_INVOKED` is defined, but I don't know whether the latter gets defined or not. Made an edit to my post.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this linking error trying to compile `paex_record_file.c`. Turns out you need to compile `pa_ringbuffer.c` before compiling the main file. There's also an external dependency on some alloc function, so you need to change 2 lines in the file.

I'm not savvy of qt but you need to do something like:

`SOURCES += pa_ringbuffer.c main.cpp`

Here's how I compile with MinGW:

**Changes inside paex_record_file.c**

```
Line 313 : data.ringBufferData = (SAMPLE *) malloc( numBytes );
Line 443 : free( data.ringBufferData );
```

**Compile with MinGW:**

```
gcc -o p_rec.exe C:\path_to_portaudio\portaudio\common\pa_ringbuffer.c \
paex_record_file.c -lportaudio \
-IC:\path_to_portaudio\portaudio\src\common
```

I didn't get the min problem, but perhaps you can try to remove the `ifdef` guard and try to recompile.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#endif
```

to

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
```